# Titanium - connect to socket.io Server

Tags: ios, sockets, socket.io, titanium

I am trying to make an simple Chat Applikation with socket.io and Titanium for IOS/Android.

I was able to get the example Skript from socket.io running on my local machine.
I can send and receive messages over my browsers.
But i cant connect with my IOS App i build in Titanium.
I dont get the connect status in the console.

Does someone knows what i am doing wrong. Or have i forgotten something?

I have tried it with the Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP function:

```
var hostname = '127.0.0.1';

    var clientSocket = Ti.Network.Socket.createTCP({
        host : hostname,
        port : 3000,
        connected : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('Client socket connected!');
            Ti.Stream.pump(e.socket, pumpCallback, 1024, true);
            e.socket.write(Ti.createBuffer({
                value : 'A message from a connecting socket.'
            }));
        },
        error : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info('Error (' + e.errorCode + '): ' + e.error);
        }
    });

    function writeCallback(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Successfully wrote to socket.');
    }

    function pumpCallback(e) {
        // Has the remote socket closed its end?
        if (e.bytesProcessed < 0) {
            Ti.API.info("Closing client socket.");
            clientSocket.close();
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (e.buffer) {
                var received = e.buffer.toString();
                Ti.API.info('Received: ' + received);
            } else {
                Ti.API.error('Error: read callback called with no buffer!');
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            Ti.API.error(ex);
            }
        }

Ti.API.info("Setting timer to connect.");
        setTimeout(function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Calling connect on client socket.");
            clientSocket.connect();
        }, 500);
```

And the code from my server:

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Output in Titanium:

```
[INFO] :   Setting timer to connect.
[INFO] :   Calling connect on client socket.
[INFO] :   Client socket connected!
[INFO] :   Closing client socket.
```

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO goes hand by hand with `socket.io.js` file which runs in the browser. You can't just replace this file with simple TCP requests.

You may try to use libraries (like [this one](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) and [this one](https://github.com/saturngod/Socket.io-with-iOS)) that allow you to create Socket.IO client on Objective-C.